# Debugger that watches jvm running a BlackBerry application on device simulator

Tags: blackberry, jvm, debugging, simulator

I need a debugger that watches jvm running a BlackBerry application on device simulator (the same way as OllyDbg is used to debug Windows applications.) Any recommends?

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry JDE and Eclipse plugins both have debugging tools built in to them.  Is there something specific you're looking for that these tools don't provide?  They're quite comprehensive - code stepping, memory monitoring, process and thread dumps, etc.